# Purpose of call with null in curry function (JavaScript implementation)

Tags: javascript, currying

In the following implementation of `curry` function [here](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/appendix_a.html#curry):

```
// curry :: ((a, b, ...) -> c) -> a -> b -> ... -> c
function curry(fn) {
  const arity = fn.length;

  return function $curry(...args) {
    if (args.length < arity) {
      return $curry.bind(null, ...args);
    }

    return fn.call(null, ...args);
  };
}
```

what's the purpose of using `call` with `null` as `this` in the `fn.call`? Wouldn't just `fn(...args)` work? I did try some examples and got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would work just fine. (The tiny difference is that it passes `undefined` instead of `null` for the `this` context).

So why did the author use `.call(null, …)`? Probably because it nicely mirrors the `.bind(null, …)` call.